# Convert string representation of JSON to JSON

Tags: swift, xcode

I have an odd question.

I have a string named string, `{"reply": "", "emoji": ":)", "time": "3"}`

Now obviously because this is a string, I cannot access it with `string["time"]`.

I need to convert it to an array (or JSON), but I cannot figure out how.

I tried SwiftyJSON

```
let b = JSON(string)

print(b["comment"]) #"null\n"
```

I tried JSONSerialisation, but that seemingly failed as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

I am using Alamofire to retrieve the JSON, when I use `.responseString`, it contains everything, but `.responseJSON` is empty, and I don't know why.

Comment: JSON is the name of a data serialization format. It is by definition a string representation of data. You can no more "convert a string representation of JSON to JSON" than you can convert a string representation of CSV to CSV, or a string representation of ASCII to ASCII. They are one and the same. When you deserialize (parse) JSON, you no longer have JSON. It sounds like what you actually want is to deserialize a JSON into a Swift object.

Comment: "I need to convert it to an array (or JSON)" The string that you have would actually only work as a dictionary object.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick-and-dirty solution with `JSONSerialization` that should get your started:

```
let string = "{\"reply\": \"\", \"emoji\": \":)\", \"time\": \"3\"}"
let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: string.data(using: .utf8)!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: String]
print(json["time"])
```

Your actual code should have more error checking, of course.